# JSON post, browser and application different times

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel-5

Before i start eating my keyboard, maybe someone can help me out here...

Im using Angular Bootstrap to set a time. After posting the time, and checking my console, i see that the selected time is posted. But after checking my log file, i see that the time is posted minus 1 hour. I've set my app => timezone to Europe/Amsterdam (ECT if im right) but still cant find what is going wrong.

Can someone help me please?

Controller:

```
public function update( EventRequest $request, $eventGuid )
{
    Log::info($request->all());
    $this->event->updateById($request, $eventGuid);
}
```

Angular post will be done as: 2016-01-27 03:45:39

Console log: 2016-01-27 03:45:39 
Laravel log: 2016-01-27 02:45:39

Comment: Post the code you are using and the output of the logs if you want someone to actually be able to help.

Comment: What do you mean "eating my keyboard"? Can you post relative code how  you get the time and send a post request?

Comment: Eating my keyboard like: getting frustrated :P - I've added some code, its not much, but this is the only thing i do actually

Comment: Add the code that creates and sends the request as well. It doesn't make sense that a timestamp would suddenly change unless you are doing separate calculations on the client/server side.